# Add class to all HTML paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML from scratch, I have no background with CSS or any web development language, during the tutorial they posted the following exercise:

Add the "intro" class to all `<p>` elements.

And then I have to change the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.intro {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding:10px;
    margin:30px;
    font-size:150%;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

To solve this, I added the class to each paragraph, but this looks highly inefficient. Is there a way that allows me to add the class to all the paragraphs?

Comment: Yes indeed, JavaScript, but @j08691 brings up a valid solution, in that you can use the tag name instead.

Comment: Which tutorial? It would be helpful to know what exactly you are being asked to do. If you are asked to add the class at runtime and are using a library such as jQuery, you just call $('p').addClass('intro'); but if you are being asked to add class="intro", you can use a string replacement in your editor.

Comment: This is plain vanilla css. The simplest solution that works is usually the best.

Comment: @Steve the question is there, all i have to do is add the class to the paragraphs. The tutorial is from w3schools.com

Answer (score 3):

`p.intro` selects all paragraphs that have the class intro. Ex: `<p class="intro">`. To apply the class to all paragraphs without having to add the class to each paragraph, change the selector to `p`

Ex:

```
p {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding:10px;
    margin:30px;
    font-size:150%;
}
```

Comment: He's looking for a better way to add the class to all paragraphs without doing it manually.

Comment: Precisely, but from the answers given, i guess there's no way to add it, and it makes more sense to do it this way, am I right?

Comment: @JoaoAmaral  The only ways to do this are via JavaScript (unnecessary), as I do above, or manually add the class to every paragraph.

Comment: okay, that answers the question :) in fact it is pretty useless to add a specific class to all the paragraphs, from what i know, which is very little, so far, thank you @j08691!

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
p{
   background-color:black;
   color:white;
   border:1px solid grey;
   padding:10px;
   margin:30px;
   font-size:150%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for how to better add the class to all paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem regarding the output page, but doesn't answer the question, is there a way to add a class to all paragraphs? After giving some thought i guess it is a bit useless unless you can override a "default" class.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in jQuery. 
    $( "p" ).addClass( "intro" );
but you need to download the jquery file to use this and other jquery features.

Comment: Or you can use plain javascript and not download anything.

Comment: i mean using only html and css, adding the class to all paragraphs.

Comment: I think by using only pure html code, you can only type the classname to each "p" tag manually

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your editor or OS. In Windows editors, typically ctrl+H will open the search&replace dialog. Put

as the search and  for the replace. In Linux/Mac, you can use sed. -i means in-place (as opposed to using a new file). The s/...part is a standard substitution call common among many Linux based programs that says find the empty tag and replace it with one having the class="intro" part.

```
sed -i '' 's/\<p\>/<p class="intro">/g' yourFile.html
```

The list of how to do it is as large as the list of editors.